# Issue with Python new_word issue

Tags: python

Don't see what I'm doing wrong here.

On a new line after where you created the first variable:

Create a new variable called new_word and set it equal to the concatenation of word, first, and pyg.

Set new_word equal to the slice from the 1st index all the way to the end of new_word. Use `[1:len(new_word)]` to do this.

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    print original
else:
    print 'empty'

word = original.lower()
first = word[0]

new_word = word + first + pyg 

newer_word = [0:len(new_word)]
```

Comment: Well, do what they told you to do `new_word[1:len(new_word)]`

Comment: "Use `[1:len(new_word)] ` to do this."  You used `[0:len(new_word)]`, which isn't a slice nor is it what you were asked to use.

Comment: use `new_word = new_word[1:]` which actually is same as stripping the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    print original
else:
    print 'empty'

word = original.lower()
first = word[0]

new_word = word + first + pyg 

newer_word = new_word[1:len(new_word)]      """ u were forgetting to which word it should slice and as mentioned u should slice from 1st index not 0 index """

print newer_word
```